# Как правильно зациклить jquery-анимацию?

Tags: jquery

Есть кнопка, у которой должен быть пульсирующий текст.
Сделал анимацию следующим образом:

```
setInterval(function () {
        $(".form button").animate({"font-size":"22px"}, 500, "linear").delay(500).animate({"font-size":"20px"}, 500, "linear");
    }, 1000);
```

Но после выполнения анимации, перед выполнением следующего цикла, есть небольшая задержка. Как правильно зациклить анимацию, чтобы задержки не было? Также как нет задержки между анимацией от большего шрифта к меньшему.

Comment: встречный вопрос, это нужно было делать только js/jq ? простой css с этим великолепно справляется.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mожет чeрез callback...

```js
setInterval(function() {
  $(".button").animate({
      "font-size": "22px"
    }, 500, "linear"),
    $(".button").animate({
      "font-size": "20px"
    }, 500, "linear");
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="button">zzzzzzzzz</span>
```